# Why is my custom exception not being rethrown/caught?

Tags: java, swing, oop, exception, non-static

So I have a class called Digicel and another one called AdminGui. I've imported the Digicel class into the AdminGui class because they're in separate packages. There are other classes in my project but I don't think they need to be mentioned for this issue.

I have a function called addCustomer in the Digicel class that writes a customer's information to a text file. But I want to check the records in the file to ensure that the customer's id number is unique and doesn't already exist in the file. For this purpose, I created a custom exception called UniqueValueException that extends the Exception class.

Unique Value Exception Class

```java
public class UniqueValueException extends Exception {
    public UniqueValueException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

In the Digicel class, I have the addCustomer function, that writes to the file, and the checkCustomerUniqueValues, that searches the file for the same customer Id.

Check Customer Unique Values Function

```java
    public static void checkCustomerUniqueValues(Customer c) throws UniqueValueException{
        Scanner inFileStream = null;
        String custID = "";
        String name = "";
        float creditBalance = 0;
        String telephone = "";
        String address = "";
        try {
            inFileStream = new Scanner(new File("Digicel_Customers.txt"));
            while (inFileStream.hasNext()) {
                custID = inFileStream.next();
                name = inFileStream.next();
                creditBalance = inFileStream.nextFloat();
                telephone = inFileStream.next();
                address = inFileStream.nextLine();
                if (custID.equals(c.getCustID())) {
                    //inFileStream is closed in finally block
                    throw new UniqueValueException("Customer ID already exists.");
                }
                else if(telephone.equals(c.getTelephone().toString())){
                    throw new UniqueValueException("Telephone number already in use.");
                }
            }   
        } 
        catch (UniqueValueException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if(inFileStream != null) {
                try {
                    inFileStream.close();
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("\nAn unexpected error occured.");
                }   
            }
        }
    }
```

Add Customer Function

```java
public String addCustomer(Customer c) throws UniqueValueException { 
        FileWriter outFileStream = null;
        Scanner input = null;
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            outFileStream = new FileWriter(new File("Digicel_Customers.txt"), true);
            try {
                checkCustomerUniqueValues(c);
            } 
            catch(UniqueValueException e){
                System.out.println("Inside addCustomer() method");
                throw e;
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                throw e;
            }


            if(c.getCustID().length() != 11){
                return "TRN is invalid - Length: " + c.getCustID().length();
            }
            
            String newCustomer = c.getCustID() + "\t" + c.getName() + "\t" + c.getCreditBalance() + "\t" + c.getTelephone().toString() + "\t" +  c.getAddress() +  "\n";    
            outFileStream.write(newCustomer);
            System.out.println("Information saved successfully!");
            super.addCustomer(c);
            digicelCustomerCount++;
            return("");
            
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            return("\nAn unexpected error occured.");
        }
        finally {
            if(outFileStream != null) {
                try {
                    outFileStream.close();
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("\nAn unexpected error occured.");
                }       
            }
            if(input != null) {
                input.close();
            }
        }
        
    }
```

In the AdminGui class, I have an action listener on a button to pass the information for the text fields to add customer function in the Digicel.

```java
        addUserButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Customer c;
                String returnString = "";
                if(!customerIdText.getText().equals("   -   -   ") && !lastNameText.getText().equals("User Last Name") && !addressText.getText().equals("Address") && !phoneText.getText().equals("876-000-0000")){
                    c = new Customer(customerIdText.getText(), lastNameText.getText(), addressText.getText(), new Telephone(Integer.parseInt(phoneText.getText().substring(0,3)), Integer.parseInt(phoneText.getText().substring(4,7)), Integer.parseInt(phoneText.getText().substring(8,12))));
                    try{
                        returnString = adminUser.addCustomer(c);
                        if(returnString != ""){
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parentFrame,returnString + " "+ phoneText.getText() + "\nPrefix - " + phoneText.getText().substring(0,3),"Form Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                        else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parentFrame,"Information Saved!","Form Submitted",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(UniqueValueException e1){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parentFrame,returnString,"Form Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parentFrame,"All fields must be filled","Form Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });
```

My issue is that in the checkCustomerUniqueValues method, the exception is thrown but it isn't caught in the addCustomer method, even though it is called in a try block. The error message for the thrown exception in checkCustomerUniqueValues is displayed in the terminal but the rest of the code in the stack still runs. The "Information saved successfully!" message shows at the bottom.

```
OOPproject.teleCompanyPKG.UniqueValueException: Customer ID already exists.
        at OOPproject.teleCompanyPKG.Digicel.checkCustomerUniqueValues(Digicel.java:182)
        at OOPproject.teleCompanyPKG.Digicel.addCustomer(Digicel.java:121)
        at OOPproject.guiPKG.AdminGui$6.actionPerformed(AdminGui.java:444)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6617)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6382)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2264)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4993)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2322)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4934)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4563)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4504)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2308)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Information saved successfully!
```

I'm really stumped on how to fix it because I have no idea why it isn't being rethrown. Send help please.

Comment: We catch it here: `} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`. Since `UniqueValueException extends Exception`, a `catch (Exception ...)` will also catch `UniqueValueException`s.

Answer (score 3):

Your `checkCustomerUniqueValues` method catches all exceptions of type `Exception`, and swallows them:

```
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Since `UniqueValueException` is a subtype of `Exception`, that catch-block catches it, and prevents it from propagating up to the caller.

Comment: I just added a catch for the UniqueValueException above the Exception catch but it still has the same result.

Comment: @Ashley I doubt that. Please edit the post, add a [MRE] and share the updated code.

Comment: @Ashley: you shouldn't be catching this exception in the same method where you throw it, and you should never catch `Exception` anyway, *ever*. Always catch *specific* exceptions.

Comment: After removing all the exception catch blocks and getting rid of UniqueValueException catch block from the checkCustomerUniqueValues method. It's working now. Thank you.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter: I don't agree with your statement that "you should never catch `Exception` anyway, *ever*". Firstly, it's very common to catch Exceptions and throw wrapper exceptions. Secondly, it's sometimes possible (and desirable) to handle an Exception even without recognizing the specific exception-type; for example, in a "process manager"–type system, if a process throws an exception, the manager should catch that and mark the process as failed (with appropriate metadata).